# ErrorDocument 404 redirect to main page change url in https

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, https

I use

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

In htaccess for redirect none pages to main page of site.
This code is working exactly for http and don't change url, but in https url is change and it isn't that was typed.

For example in http if one person type http://mydomin.com/a and this page be not exist, the main page loades in current url, but in https the main page loades in real url (https://mydomin.com/index.php) in fact the url is changing, but I don't want.

Now, how do I force https that it don't change url?

Comment: Welcome! Can you post the rest of your `.htaccess` file, specifically anything related to HTTPS?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sharj4030.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sharj4030.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sharj4030.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sharj4030.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://sharj4030.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sharj4030.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`